# counter_cache with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, conditional-statements, counter-cache

I know I can use callbacks but this should be feasible. I did lengthly searching and no result. This is what I thought would have worked.

```
def User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :documents
  has_many :draft_docs     , :class_name => 'Document', :conditions => { :status => 'draft' }
  has_many :published_docs , :class_name => 'Document', :conditions => { :status => 'published' }
  has_many :private_docs   , :class_name => 'Document', :conditions => { :status => 'private' }
end

def Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user      , :counter_cache => true
  belongs_to :user      , :inverse_of => :draft_docs    , :counter_cache => true
  belongs_to :user      , :inverse_of => :published_docs, :counter_cache => true
  belongs_to :user      , :inverse_of => :private_docs  , :counter_cache => true
end
```

Not working as planned, as you can see its updating documents_count instead of published_docs_count.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :021 > User.reset_counters 2, :published_docs  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `documents` WHERE `documents`.`user_id` = 2 AND `documents`.`status` = 'published'
   (2.2ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `documents_count` = 233 WHERE `users`.`id` = 2
 => true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [counter_culture](https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture) gem.

- Add three columns to the `users` table.

  ```
  add_column :users, :draft_documents_count, :integer, null: false, default: 0
  add_column :users, :published_documents_count, :integer, null: false, default: 0
  add_column :users, :private_documents_count, :integer, null: false, default: 0
  ```
- Decorate the `Document` model

  ```
  class Document
    counter_culture :user, :column_name => Proc.new do |doc|
      if %w(draft published private).include?(doc.status) 
        "{doc.status}_documents_count"
      end
    end    
  end
  ```
- Run a command in the console to seed the counts for current rows

  ```
  Document.counter_culture_fix_counts
  ```

#### Old answer

You can supply the counter column name (apart from `true`) to the `counter_cache` option.

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :draft_docs, 
                                   :counter_cache => :draft_docs_count
  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :published_docs, 
                                   :counter_cache => :published_docs_count
  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :private_docs, 
                                   :counter_cache => :private_docs_count
end
```

Comment: It doesn't work, It still only tries to update documents_count.

Comment: This does not work. At least not in Rails 4. I suspect it does not work in Rails 3.x either.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you use the same name for all the associations.

```
belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
belongs_to :user_doc, :class_name => "User", 
           :inverse_of => :draft_docs, :counter_cache => :draft_docs_count
```

This functionality is implemented by adding a callback to increment the count, and in your case, the target is `document.user` since you used the same name for everything.

Comment: I don't see how this answer is different from the one provided by Harish Shetty. On SO it is recommended to bring something new to a question when replying. :)

Comment: This does not work in Rails 4. I suspect it will not work in Rails 3.x either. Have you tested this?